# "Run in background" button doesn't show up in ProgressMonitorDialog

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to use a ProgressMonitorDialog to execute a (long) task, but I would like the user to be able to "Run it in background".

Unfortunately, this button doesn't appear and I can't find out the reasons of this problem.
Here is my code:

```
ProgressMonitorDialog pmd = new ProgressMonitorDialog(shell);

    try {
        pmd.run(true, true, new IRunnableWithProgress() {

            @Override
            public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws InvocationTargetException,
                    InterruptedException {

                monitor.beginTask("Refactoring in progress", IProgressMonitor.UNKNOWN);

                File root = new File(file.getProject().getLocation().toOSString()); //The root is here

                browseAndProcess(root, file.getName(), newFileName, monitor);

                monitor.done();

            }
        });
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is a sample of my current result : https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHSQP.jpg

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong ?
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard `ProgressMonitorDialog` does not support the run in background option.

The dialog which has this option is `ProgressMonitorFocusJobDialog` which is not public. It can only be accessed by using a `Job`.

Using the `setUser(true)` method of `Job` before scheduling the job will tell the job manager to display this progress dialog after a short delay.

You can also get the dialog shown immediately using:

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getProgressService().showInDialog(shell, job);
```